# Where is data returned by physical carrier sensing is stored?

Tags: c, linux, wifi, driver

I want to know where is data returned by physical carrier sensing mechanism is stored.
after doing research found this.
In **ath9k/main.c** there is one function called **ath9k_get_survey()** which inter calls **ath_update_survey_stats()** function.
In **ath_update_survey_stats()** , ***struct survey_info*** members are getting initialized.

One of the member is ***channel_time_busy:*** amount of time the primary channel was sensed busy.
I want to confirm if this member holds the channel busy time value returned by physical carrier sensing mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Some detail of the asked function obtained [HERE](http://dox.ipxe.org/ath9k__main_8c.html#ab6ef9f31bd686ccfeb32d02d695b5fd8) or [here](https://dev.openwrt.org/browser/trunk/package/mac80211/patches/570-ath9k_bb_hang_check_fix.patch?rev=25359):

```
struct survey_info *survey

if (cc->cycles > 0) {
   survey->filled |= SURVEY_INFO_CHANNEL_TIME |
                SURVEY_INFO_CHANNEL_TIME_BUSY |
                SURVEY_INFO_CHANNEL_TIME_RX |
                SURVEY_INFO_CHANNEL_TIME_TX;
   survey->channel_time += cc->cycles / div;
   survey->channel_time_busy += cc->rx_busy / div;
   survey->channel_time_rx += cc->rx_frame / div;
   survey->channel_time_tx += cc->tx_frame / div;
}
```

So the answer should be yes.

Comment: Ya thats what documentation says, but no where it is mentioned that it is data returned by physical carrier sensing and i am confused. So are you sure about it.

Comment: It "should" be it depend if there is fragmentation, you'll not have the full time here but in typical case it is.